# jquery sortable ui function on elements that were appended

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using the sortable ui for jquery on a list-group which works perfectly fine. I also have a function to add elements to the list group:

```
    $('#addTask').click(function(){
        var name = $("#taskName").val();
        var num = $('li[id=taskOrder]').length+1;
        $("#taskpriority").append('<li id="taskOrder" class="list-group-item list-group-item-dark d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" draggable="true" style="display: block;">'+name+'<span class="badge badge-dark badge-pill">'+num+'</span></li>');

    });
```

However once the new list group is added, it is not draggable. All the other elements are except for the one added.

Here is a jsfiddle of the situation http://jsfiddle.net/yn8wxu9q/

Comment: Note - you are duplicating `id`s -> `.append('<li id="taskOrder"`, but `id` by definition should be unique. Should be `class`

Comment: You can simply add `$(".list-group-sortable").sortable("refresh");` after appending the new `li` List Item. **Sean** has also pointed out the issue with duplicating `ID`'s. **ID's** should be unique and not duplicated. Here is a [**JsFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/xwqktad7/)

Comment: @NewToJS that does make it sortable however the animation is weird, a bullet point appears on the left.

Comment: @user2989367 that sounds like a different issue with `css`. As you can see from the [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/xwqktad7/) I have provided it does not show bullet points.

Comment: @NewToJS Yes it does we just dont see them, here I put it in a container to show you. http://jsfiddle.net/xwqktad7/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just add `.sortable()` to the end of (or directly after) the `append()` function. Like this:

```
$('#addTask').click(function(){
    var name = $("#taskName").val();
    var num = $('li[id=taskOrder]').length+1;
    $("#taskpriority").append('<li id="taskOrder" class="list-group-item list-group-item-dark d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" draggable="true" style="display: block;">'+name+'<span class="badge badge-dark badge-pill">'+num+'</span></li>').sortable();

});
```

this will make the new element you are adding sortable with jquery's sortable funtionality.

**Edit/update**

Your "bullet point" issue is due to your addition of the `placeHolderClass` attribute when you are declaring your elements as sortable when you first build the sortable list of elements.

just add the `placeHolderClass` to the sortable function in my code. Like this:

```
$('#addTask').click(function(){
    var name = $("#taskName").val();
    var num = $('li[id=taskOrder]').length+1;
    $("#taskpriority").append('<li id="taskOrder" class="list-group-item list-group-item-dark d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" draggable="true" style="display: block;">'+name+'<span class="badge badge-dark badge-pill">'+num+'</span></li>').sortable({ placeholderClass: 'list-group-item' });

});
```

this addition will make it like you had it to start, without a bullet point.

Comment: That fixed the sortable issue like mentioned in a previous comment but it adds a bullet point and breaks the css as shown here http://jsfiddle.net/xwqktad7/1/ is there a different solution or a way to improve on this?

Comment: My update shows you how to "Fix" the issue you are describing. The bullet point not being there is because of a css class you applied when making the list sortable in the first place, the css class just needs to be applied in the sortable function attribute again. Check my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

you can update code like this, we need to initialize short every time when you add new element from query or javascript

```
InitShort() //initialize first time
$('#addTask').click(function(){
        var name = $("#taskName").val();
        var num = $('li[id=taskOrder]').length+1;
        $("#taskpriority").append('<li id="taskOrder" class="list-group-item list-group-item-dark d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" draggable="true" style="display: block;">'+name+'<span class="badge badge-dark badge-pill">'+num+'</span></li>');

    InitShort()//initialize after add new item time

    });


 function InitShort() {

$('.list-group-sortable').sortable({
        placeholderClass: 'list-group-item'
    }).bind('sortupdate', function(e, ui) {
        $('li[id=taskOrder]').each(function(index, element){
            $(this).find('span').html(index+1);
        });
    });
}
```